# Xcode 7.1 scn settings

Tags: xcode, swift, scenekit, ios9.1

Can any body help me understand,
how I can load a `.scn` scene file with all settings in SceneKit (Swift Programming Lang)?

issue is:
When I create and set up a `.scn` Scene in Xcode I make visual (light, fog etc.) decorating, all is fine. And if I play in Xcode it works.

But when i load scene in ViewController I got really bad visual decorating.

In Xcode:
[image: Xcode version]

In the Simulator:
[image]
My GameController code is simple:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit

class GameController: UIViewController {

    var scnView: SCNView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        scnView.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/game.scn")
        scnView.showsStatistics = true
    }    

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```